# how to change stepper direction through limit switch

Tags: limit, direction, stepper, adafruit-circuitpython

I am working on a project and am trying to write code for this project in circuitpython on a esp32 s2 board.

Currectly I don't have the hardware setup ready to function so I can't test codes I've written. So all I have to base my findings on are thought experiments and trying to understand what the code will do (which is a good training at it's own IMHO).

One of the difficulties, and the one for this question, is that I am dealing with getting the stepper motor to change direction when an (optical) limit switch is triggered (so far so good i think), but i will also need to keep it in this "reversed" direction once it no longer triggers that switch.

One way, to do so, seems to make it stop looking at the first limit switch as soon as it is triggered and start looking at the switch at the opposite end instead as well as change the direction. Unfortunately i understand this but have no clue how to set this up in code. When it reaches the trigger it this end it needs to do something else entirely so i am really only dealing with this one switch triggered change of direction during initialisation.

```
while True:
    stepper_motor.onestep(direction=stepper.FORWARD, style=stepper.DOUBLE)
    time.sleep(Interstep_delay)

    while switch_top.value is False         
        stepper_motor.onestep(direction=stepper.BACKWARD, style=stepper.DOUBLE)
        Step_count = Step_count + 1
        time.sleep(Interstep_delay)

        while switch_bottom.value is False
             #stop stepper motor
             Total_count = Step_count.
```

This is the code I have for now, but it just doesn't feel correct to me. Mainly because I (think I) make it look at the bottom switch but I don't make it stop looking at the top switch but I have no idea how to change this in a correct manner.

Any thought and suggestions are welcome.

Kind greats

PS: I added my code to clarify what I am doing and willing to do. Please help me with the thought experiment. This question is ofcourse not intended for me to end up with a working code still don't understand.

Since post i changed code to this

```
# initiasation
leds[0] = (255, 0, 0)
while True:
    while switch_top.value:
        stepper.onestep(direction=stepper.FORWARD, style=stepper.DOUBLE)
        time.sleep(Interstep_delay)
    if switch_bottom.value:
        stepper.onestep(direction=stepper.BACKWARD, style=stepper.DOUBLE)
        Step_count = Step_count + 1
        time.sleep(Interstep_delay)
    elif switch_bottom.value is False:
        Step_count = Total_steps
        leds[0] = (0, 255, 0)
        if switch_start is False:
            leds[0] = (0, 0, 255)
            game_function()
```

but i am still in doubt if it would actually do what i intend it to do.

Comment: Asking us to help with a problem when you don't even know you have a problem seems a bit of a stretch.

Comment: I agree, from your (and probably others) point of view, never the less, information on the likelyhood and why (if so) would be very helpfull to me at this point. I am just not reading code very easily and can overlook the obvious without knowing i am overlooking.